# Can you use an enhanced for each loop to add elements to an array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I know you cannot use an enhanced for loop to change the array elements, but what about adding things into an array?

Many thanks

Comment: Are you talking about an array or an array list? As they are a little different from each other.

Comment: This question needs to be edited. Please give more details about what you are asking. Maybe provide pseudo-code of what you are trying to do, what input you are expecting to use, and what output you would like to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never "add" an element to an array. It is a fixed-size data structure, with or without an enhanced for loop. All you can do is to allocate an array, and then set its elements.

It doesn't make sense to allocate the array you are iterating in the enhanced for loop - what then are you iterating? - and as you have stated in the question, you cannot set array elements (directly) in a for loop.

So, no.

Comment: An `ArrayList` (a `List` that is backed by an array) on the other hand, you *can* add to, but the "array" there is only internal, and the add operations may cause a new array creation (with increased size) and array copy under the covers.